# C++ - List files of directory and save output result on txt

Tags: c++, list, file

I need to output the result of this code to a txt. When I try it saves only one line.

```
using namespace std;
std::string c;

void list_dir(const char *path) {
struct dirent *entry;
DIR *dir = opendir(path);
if (dir == NULL) {
   return;
}
while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
c = entry->d_name;
cout << c << endl;
}
closedir(dir);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the output and what output do you expect?

Comment: I see you're using POSIX's filesystem API. Have you considered using the C++ Standard Filesystem library instead?

Comment: "When I try it saves only one line." - your program doesn't "save" anything - it only calls `puts` which prints to `stdout`. I assume that's what you mean?

Comment: Please focus your question on either achieving more than one line or one getting the output into a file.

Comment: Please upgrade the shown code fragment to a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Use FileSystem Header.
Ex :

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
 
int main()
{
    std::fstream fs("Output.txt")
    fs::current_path(fs::temp_directory_path());
    fs::create_directories("sandbox/a/b");
    std::ofstream("sandbox/file1.txt");
    fs::create_symlink("a", "sandbox/syma");
    for(auto& p: fs::recursive_directory_iterator("sandbox"))
        fs.write(p.path());

    
    fs::remove_all("sandbox");
}
```

This Creates and returns all the Files in the Directory

Comment: I did not get the impression that OP is asking about creating.... and I get confused by "create all the files in the directory" either a file is there (then it does not need creating) or is not there (then it is not among "all" and why create it).

Comment: I Couldn't get you

Comment: "This Creates (... snip ... ) all the Files in the Directory" confuses me, because I did not get the impression that OP is asking about creating files.